# Path is wrong, what to do?

Tags: c++, qt, file

I'd like to write something to my path.

My code is following

```
QString Log::logPacketsPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/logs/Packets/";
int userID = 1;
QString text = "test 1 2 3";


QFile logPacketFile(logPacketsPath + "UserID: " + userID + " - " +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy") + ".log");

if (logPacketFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Append))
{
    QTextStream out(&logPacketFile);
    out << "[" << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy, hh:mm:ss") << "]: " << text << "\n";
    logPacketFile.close();
}
```

But it only creates the file named "UserID" with nothing in it.

Do you know where the mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which OS you're using, but ':' is invalid in a Windows filename.

Next, you should [flush](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextstream.html#flush) the `QTextStream` before closing the file:

```
out.flush();
logPacketFile.close();
```

or create additional scope:

```
{
    QTextStream out(&logPacketFile);
    out << "[" << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy, hh:mm:ss") << "]: " << text << "\n";
}
logPacketFile.close();
```

Also, as Chemobyl has pointed out, you can get into trouble by concatinating the `int userID` to your filepath. I'd suggest using string formatting to create the filename:

```
QString logPacketFile("%1UserID%2 - %3.log")
         .arg(logPacketsPath)
         .arg(userID)
         .arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I did the things you told me. The mistake was the ":". However, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert `int` to `QString`:

Use `QString::number().`

Output with your current code:

```
"C:/.../logs/Packets/UserID [bad symbols here] - 17.11.14.log"
```

Output with

```
QFile logPacketFile(logPacketsPath + "UserID " + QString::number(userID) + " - " +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy") + ".log");//removed colon
```

is:

```
"C:/.../logs/Packets/UserID 1 - 17.11.14.log"
```

It is source of big troubles. See next:

```
int userID = 70;
QString text = "test 1 2 3";
QFile logPacketFile(logPacketsPath + "UserID " + userID + " - " +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yy") + ".log");
```

Output:

```
.../UserID F - 17.11.14.log"
```

Note `F`, not a `70` because [operator+](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-2b-36) thought that you use simple char and `70` in char is `F`:

http://www.asciitable.com/

So I strongly suggest you to use `QString::number` to prevent errors.

Comment: Thank you! But I thought I don't have to convert int to QString. The mistake was to use ":" in filename.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit QString has no constructor which takes int: 4.8 http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-2 and 5 http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-2

Comment: @user3874443 You should convert, : is a mistake but convert int to qstring is important too. I added better explanation about this, see it please.